# How to fix 'Failed to compile in ./src/global.scss'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, node-sass

I had created project in ionic v4 and I got error in ./src/global.scss, see error in the below

```
>ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/global.scss)
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
[ng] Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
[ng]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
[ng]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[ng]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[ng]     at Object.sassLoader (/home/manish/newionic_workspace/latest100days/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:46:72)
[ng] ERROR in ./src/theme/variables.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/theme/variables.scss)
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
[ng] Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
[ng]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
[ng]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[ng]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[ng]     at Object.sassLoader (/home/manish/newionic_workspace
/latest100days/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:46:72)
```

I have used the rebuild command also

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

but it's not work

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --save-dev node-sass` or `npm rebuild node-sass --force` ?

Comment: It's work Thanks  @Nenad Radak

Comment: Great i will post it then as answer

Comment: @NenadRadak Could you describe a little bit about why this command is necessary and why this error occurred in first first even thought I had ``node-sass`` installed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `npm install --save-dev node-sass` or `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

Answer (score 1):

You have to give global permission first, add sudo at the beggining.

sudo npm i node-sass

Hope this works for you too!